# Spring: Inject static member (System.in) via constructor

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, constructor-injection

I wrote some sort of console client for a simple application.
To be more flexible, I thought it would be nice to only depend on `java.io.Input-/OutputStream`, instead of accessing `System.in/out` directly.

I renamed the class `ConsoleClient` to `StreamClient`, added setters and made sure that the instance fields are used instead of `System.in/out`.

At the moment my client code looks like this:

```
ApplicationContext appCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("...");
StreamClient cc = (StreamClient) appCtx.getBean("streamClient");
cc.setInputStream(System.in);
cc.setOutputStream(System.out);
cc.run();   // start client
```

### Question:

Is there a way to move lines 3 and 4 into the Spring configuration (preferably constructor injection)?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `<util:constant ... />`:

```
<util:constant id = "out" static-field="java.lang.System.out" />
```

Comment: More information on this topic:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can explicitly create a bean using `System.out` (which I think is what you're asking). However you can create a bean that uses a factory class / method to return an object (in this case `System.out`)

```
<bean id="streamOut" class="examples.StreamFactory"
      factory-method="getSystemOut"/>
```